# How to define a rule to require all in Prolog?

Tags: prolog

Having the knowledge base:

```
must_have(user, car, blue).
must_have(user, car, yellow).
must_have(user, bike, green).
```

How to define:

```
is_a_collector(X):-must_have(X, car, blue),
                   must_have(X,car,yellow),
                   must_have(X,bike,green).
```

without expliciting all the conditions?

I say this because the knowledge domain is large and I want to define a rule that catches many conditions.

I'm using Swi-Prolog.

Comment: I'm not sure this question is clear. Does your database of `must_have` apply to only one `user`, and so to be a collector, literally ALL of the `must_have` would apply to the user `X`? Or are there many users and you want a certain subset of the data to apply to a user before you consider them a collector? Your title says "all" but your text says, *...define a rule that catches **many** conditions*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For SWI-Prolog, you can use `foreach/2` from [`library(aggregate)`](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/man?section=aggregate). Read the documentation on what exactly it does, but in effect, it creates the conjunction that you need.

```
?- foreach(must_have(X, _, _), X = user).
true.

?- foreach(must_have(X, _, _), X = foo).
false.
```

Or if you want to define a predicate,

```
is_a_collector(X) :- foreach(must_have(Y, _, _), Y = X).
```

However, @lurker is right that your question is a bit unclear. The proposed solution, too, feels somehow weird. At the very least, your database should contain other tables if you want to be able to state any queries that don't return truisms. At the moment, the first query above asks:

"Does every `must_have/3` fact have `user` as its first argument?"

For that purpose, you could have used `forall/2` directly, because you don't need a conjunction.

And what are you going to do with the answer to this?

Comment: In fact, I'm new to logic programming. I'm defining requirements for a certain methodology in a knowledge base, then in the final program user will say what elements (in the example vehicle/colors) he has and if he have all the requirements he will be given a full score. I don't know if I was clear enough, english isn't my primary language.

Comment: @RedDragon It sort of makes sense. Once you can "fill in" the anonymous variables with actual constraints, it will become a bit more useful. You should also consider using a constraint library, for example `library(clpfd)`.